# Weird behavior of coalescing operator (??) in php

Tags: php

Can someone please explain, why the results are different in below two cases?

```
<?php

echo ((7)??0 / (15)??1);

echo "<br><br>";

echo (((7)??0) / ((15)??1));
?>
```

```
7<br><br>0.46666666666667
```

Comment: For what it's worth, you don't need to add parenthesis around individual numbers or wrapping the entire `echo` argument and in in my opinion too many parenthesis hurt legibility. Compare with https://3v4l.org/qHPX9#v8.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Operator Precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) in the PHP manual.

`??` has higher precendance than `/` so in the first example since `7` is a true value it wins.

In the second example, the parentheses force precedence.

Comment: Wow. That's very interesting. Does that mean in the first case it took whole "0 / (15)??1" as second value for the operator? That feels like a bug, is it's not within quotes. :D

Comment: If it was within quotes then it would be a string

Comment: True. That's what makes it feel really weird. But I tested with another sample. "echo ((null)??5 / (15)??1);" and you are right on point, it's definitely operator precedence which is causing this behavior. Though this does feel weird.

Comment: @AbhishekAnand Look at this `$result = $a ?? $b ?? $c ?? false;`. Maybe that helps to understand it more. This checks $a for null, then $b then $c and may takes false. Works not like the typical  a + b or $a && $b conditions.  So you can chain `??` as often as you want.

Comment: @Foobar yup aware of that one. This one caught me completely off-guard in a complex code, and sent on a goose chase till I found coalescing was causing it.